# Random item from array returns only index location, not actual value

Tags: javascript, html, css, arrays, mouseover

```
var borderColors = ["rgb(244, 66, 215)", "rgb(119, 0, 247)", "rgb(0, 65, 247)", "rgb(0, 209, 247)", "rgb(0, 247, 86)", "rgb(205, 247, 0)","rgb(247, 90, 0)"]

var borders = document.querySelectorAll(".borders")

for (var i = 0; i < borders.length; i++) {
    borders[i].addEventListener("mouseover", function() {
    var randomColor = [Math.floor(Math.random() * borderColors.length)]
    console.log(randomColor)
    this.style.borderColor = randomColor
})
}
```

randomColor comes back as the array index location but not the actual value of the array item. If I replace randomColor with an rgb value after this.style.borderColor it will change the color, but the randomized value does not work. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You need to access the array with the random generated index: `this.style.borderColor = borderColors[randomColor]`.

Comment: `var randomColor = borderColors[Math.floor...];` - you have array index brackets around the right part you just forgot to put the array in front of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to assign the color not the random index, to do this call the item from the array using the randomly generated index like :

```
this.style.borderColor = borderColors[randomColor];
```

```js
var borderColors = ["rgb(244, 66, 215)", "rgb(119, 0, 247)", "rgb(0, 65, 247)", "rgb(0, 209, 247)", "rgb(0, 247, 86)", "rgb(205, 247, 0)", "rgb(247, 90, 0)"]

var borders = document.querySelectorAll(".borders")

for (var i = 0; i < borders.length; i++) {
  borders[i].addEventListener("mouseover", function() {
    var randomColor = [Math.floor(Math.random() * borderColors.length)];
    this.style.borderColor = borderColors[randomColor];
  })
}
```

```css
div.borders {
  height: 45px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 43px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="borders">Hover me</div>
<br>
<div class="borders">Hover me</div>
<br>
<div class="borders">Hover me</div>
```

Comment: You're welcome, if the answer is what you're looking for Mark it as the **[correct answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)** for the future readers.